# mysql if statement true select more data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been looking around on the net at SQL IF statements and i cannot seem to get my head around them. here is what i currently have

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = '$UserHomeTown[0]' OR deliver = '1' OR post = '1'
```

but if `deliver = 1` i need to SELECT location1 and compare it against `$UserHomeTown[1]`,

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = '$UserHomeTown[0]' OR post = '1' OR IF(deliver == '1')THEN location1 = '$UserHomeTown[1]'
```

But i am having no luck.

what i need is

1. select all items from $UserHomeTown[0],
2. select all items that have post set to 1,
3. select all items that have deliver set to 1 if $UserHomeTown[1] is equal to location1

Comment: Did you try using and for the last condition? e.g. `SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = '$UserHomeTown[0]' OR post = '1' OR (deliver = '1' and location1 = '$UserHomeTown[1]')`

Comment: Thank you @NoGray, i can see what was wrong now. it makes perfect sense after seeing your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` in `WHERE` clause -

```
WHERE
location = '$UserHomeTown[0]' OR 
post = '1' OR
  CASE
    WHEN deliver='1' THEN location1='$UserHomeTown[1]'
    ELSE ''
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` `OR` exchange of if or case in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE 
location = '$UserHomeTown[0]' OR post = '1' OR 
(deliver == '1' and location1 = '$UserHomeTown[1]')
```